# Could not load file or assembly on MCRTEXE.CPP When trying to Debug on C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I'm fairly new with little to zero knowledge in C++ and I already tried searching for the same issue but can't find one that matches exactly to my problem.

My problem is that I have written a C++ CLR console app in VS2019, add reference to a DLL (Microsoft.Sharepoint dll) and was able to build/rebuild the project with no error. I am able to access all the methods or classes inside the dll files in my code but whenever I try to debug or run the program I get the error saying that the system cannot find the dll file.

The error happens inside the MCRTEXE.cpp from which I understand is a C source file used by the system to set the environment of your project (you can correct me on this one lol).

Here's the error message:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

[ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bin0A.png)

I checked and can say that the dll are in the project directory so I'm not sure why it keeps on saying that it cannot find the file.

I'm sure I'm missing on some setup but I was hoping you could pinpoint it to me.

TIA!